# Multi-Factor Beta Help

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, beta, quantitative

I'm supposed to find a risk factor that could explain a stock (I chose Netflix) returns.

Then, I am to calculate the beta with respect to the factor I suggested as part of a multi-factor model with the other factor is the market.

I have no idea where to start...I think an appropriate risk factor would be something like interest rate risk, as Netflix has started to produce lots of original content, and borrowing from lenders with a changing interest rate would seriously impact the amount Netflix can use to finance its new shows, but I don't know how to find the beta for the stock using the multi-factor model.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

please check out the forum rules, your question is off-topic as it is too basic for this forum.

But since stack-exchange is for getting answers, here are some hints based on my understanding of your question:

- you are looking for a beta, i.e. a regression coefficient that "describes" the relation between your chosen "risk-factor" and Netflix' returns
- you could do that by running a linear regression which has the returns as the dependent variable (y) and your chosen explaining variables (=independent variables) on the right side (x in the simple regression below) as follows:

$y=a+bx+ϵ$ (simple linear regression with one independent variable)

Your estimate of b (= beta, or regression coefficient for IV x) is then:

$b=Cov(y,x)/Var(x)$ (note that this is an estimate and might not be the true parameter).

**What can you do to solve your task?**

- first, have a look at regression techniques, specifically start with linear regressions
- Activate the "Data Analysis" Add-on in Excel
- get data for the returns and all independent variables that you want to include and copy them into an Excel sheet (e.g. from yahoo finance; be careful to match the daily/weekly/monthly/yearly returns to the according values of your independent variables)
- go to Data, Data Analysis and input the Data from your sheet under "Linear Regression"
- run a linear regression, Excel will give you an output with "Coefficients" which are your betas

**What to keep in mind?**

- be careful to include independent variables that make sense; your best starting point is to read up on the CAPM
- try to understand what you are doing when you estimate such a regression
- a linear regression might not be the best fit, i.e. might not be the best function to represent your data
- there are way better tools for this than Excel